# show all database rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database table which has the following columns:

1. ProductID
2. Product name
3. Product Category

How I can print all products in a certain category (e.g just show products in the shoes category)?  Sorry if this is simple; I'm just starting out with web development.

Comment: i bet you could find the answer in less than an hour via google;

Comment: `SELECT * FROM myTable where category = 'Shoes'` is a good starting point

Comment: Now find yourself a tutorial on how to access a database from PHP, preferably one that uses MySQLi or PDO rather than the old deprecated MySQL extension

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductCategory='Shoes'

Answer (score 1):

Use following SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table_name
WHERE ProductCategory = 'your_category_value';
```

If you want to specify the output columns.
Use

```
SELECT column_name_1, column_name_2
FROM your_table_name
WHERE ProductCategory = 'your_category_value';
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for this, however when put this into my page, then run the code, i cant see anything 
`<?php 

$catagory=$_GET["q"];


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
  
@mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE catagory  = '$catagory%' ")or die('You need enter a catagoryE ' );

echo"id $prodID";

?>`

Comment: For debugging I suggest don't suppress the output. And in your WHERE clause, you used "%". If you want to match exactly what the category is, just take off the "%". If you want to search any category includes a phase, I guess you may want WHERE category like 'category%'. I would change your code to `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE catagory = '$catagory' ")or die('You need enter a catagoryE ' );`

Comment: For best practice, I recommend you to use sprintf(). So your query would be like ` $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '%s'", $category);`